# How can I compile mono Hello World?

Tags: mono, c#

I have Ubuntu 11.04 with this mono:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-5ubuntu3)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
```

I'm trying to run this:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }
}
```

and I get those errors:

```
ThinkPad-X201-Tablet:~/Desktop$ gmcs hello.cs
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: The class System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute could not be loaded, used in gmcs
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute
** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:9128): WARNING **: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe mtoken: 0x0a0003d2
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that should be static void Main(string[] args) ?

Comment: @Darknight I tried it, same errors. and the Hello World code is from here: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does compile flawlessly on my setup.

You should have this package installed:

- mono-2.0-devel

This should draw all required dependencies for a command line compile.
If you want more comfort, I would recommend installing the monodevelop package.